# ArcGIS: add where clause to new feature layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I would like to add a where clause to a new feature layer. I have tried the following:

```
options {
...
where: whereClause
}
new FeatureLayer(url, options);
```

The above does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the method **[setDefinitionExpression](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#setdefinitionexpression)** like this:

```
featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'South Carolina'");
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers,

Raúl